# rails - ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex - Getting a SET character count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to generate a secure random 45 character key. I tried:

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(45)
```

But that returns far more than 45 characters, it's in the 60+ range. Any thoughts? How can you generate a securerandom for a set character count?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

The argument n specifies the length of the random length. The length of the result string is twice of n.

So, if you want 45 you could set it to 23 wich will return 46 characters and then take the first 45. Of course taking the first 45 characters of a longer string would work too.

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(23)[0...45]
```